# The schema content is outdated and no longer in sync with the documents view

Tags: mongodb, compass

MongoDB Compass Visualizer does not return the report!
If we hit "Analyze" it says "The schema content is outdated and no longer in sync with the documents.

Comment: Can you share that which kind of report you want from Compass?

Comment: Just to analyze the schema in the database!
one review document it is working fine but when I want to analyze the tours, it does not return anything!